# What's the point of this "reflector" that comes with my Godox SL-150W Light?

Tags: light

I can't figure out what this piece that came with my Godox SL-150W is supposed to do. It doesn't seem to be mentioned in the manual that came with it, but I might have missed it due to not knowing the terminology:

[image]
[image]

The pictures I see online when looking it up all have an actual reflector on the front (this photo is from B&H's website):

[image]

I thought maybe it had some kind of focusing, narrow beam effect, but leaving the light on with this "reflector" on makes the device overheat and shut off after about 10 minutes. I also was thinking that it might protect the LED's when storing or transporting the light, but that seems unlikely given that there's a huge hole in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your second guess is right: that it's a cover to protect the COB LED if you ever have to pack up the light and travel with it. It's shaped like that because it's probably the same one they use as [a protection cap for the AD600 bulb](https://www.adorama.com/fplfxp002.html); the AD600 also has a Bowens S mount, and its bulb physically protrudes.

The hole in the cap is probably to help with the bulb/LED cooling if you had to pack it up while it was still hot.

Comment: That's it, thank you!

Comment: @Jake, you're welcome!

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a [snoot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snoot), used to narrow(*) the light beam from the flash (sort of a reverse-softbox).

(*) Can't say "focus" because is works mostly by cutting off the excess light, not by redirecting it.

Comment: Interesting - it does do that, in that by blocking most of the light it does narrow it - but it makes the light overheat when the room is room temperature, so if that's the case, it's a poorly built one